# fancy box, some sites not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, fancybox-2

I'm fairly new to using fancy box but i seem to have it set up correctly. I want to display other websites in the box.

when i use this code, everything is perfect!

```
<a class="iframe SecondaryCircles" id="Sec3" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/" data-type="iframe" title=""></a>
```

however if i change the url to http://www.twitter.com/

```
<a class="iframe SecondaryCircles" id="Sec3" href="http://www.twitter.com/" data-type="iframe" title=""></a>
```

all that appears is a blank fancy box! does anybody know why this is happening? am i making a mistake or will some sites just not display?

any help would be very appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Websites can instruct the browser not to display them inside (foreign) frames, via the `X-Frames-Options` header, and that is exactly what twitter does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect its the X-frame blocking. Some sites dont allow you to embed there site in an iframe. to prevent click-jacking. [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: i see! so there is no way around this?

Comment: Not with a simple iframe no. Extreme measures would be to get the webpage as a stream but it may not work or display as expected.